# Simplicial set as a colimit

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

> Let $K \in \mathrm{Set}_{\Delta}$ be a simplicial set. Then $K$ is the colimit of the diagram 
>   $$F \colon \Delta/K \to \mathrm{Set}_{\Delta} \, $$
>   that assigns to each $\Delta^n \to K$ the standard $n$-simplex $\Delta^n$.

This should be just about unravelling the definition of a limit cone, but I don't know how to rigorously prove this. A cone under $F$ is an object $x \in \mathrm{Set}_{\Delta}$ together with a natural transformation $\eta \colon F \Rightarrow \Delta( x)$, where $\Delta(x)$ stands for the diagonal functor.

$K$ is a cone under $F$, since a natural transformation $\eta \colon F \Rightarrow \Delta(K)$ is just a series of morphisms $\eta_f \colon F(\Delta^n \xrightarrow{f} K) \to K$, that is, a map $\Delta^n \to K$, which is given by $\eta_f = f$ (though I'm probably wrong). But how is that cone under $F$ a colimit cone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remark that this has nothing to do with simplicial sets specifically, the same is true for any presheaf category. Another way to state the result is to say that the identity is the left Kan extension of Yoneda along itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of $\eta : F \Rightarrow \Delta(K)$ is correct (though you should check that it is natural—this is an easy task!)

Let $X$ be a simplicial set and let $\theta : F \Rightarrow \Delta(X)$ be another cone. Then you can define $u : K \to X$ as follows. First note that there are natural isomorphisms $K_n \cong \mathrm{Set}_{\Delta}(\Delta^n, K)$ and $X_n \cong \mathrm{Set}_{\Delta}(\Delta^n, X)$ by the Yoneda lemma; and then note that there is a map $\mathrm{Set}_{\Delta}(\Delta^n, K) \to \mathrm{Set}_{\Delta}(\Delta^n, X)$ given by $f \mapsto \theta_f$. This induces functions $u_n : K_n \to X_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which piece together to form a map of simplicial sets $u : K \to X$.

Finally, check that $\Delta(u) : \Delta(K) \Rightarrow \Delta(X)$ is the unique natural transformation such that $\Delta(u) \circ \eta = \theta$.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is much clearer now.